# Type 'WatchManager' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, watchos

I try use WatchManager.swift in exists project.

```
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {


    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {

    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {

    }
}
```

but I have trouble on build my project

```
Swift Compiler Error Group - Type 'WatchManager' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'
```

Also in issue navigator i see error

```
Candidate has non-matching type '(WCSession, WCSessionActivationState, Error?) -> ()'
```

I already tried:

- remove derived data
- clean project
- clean builds folder
- reload project from git
- copy file from another project
- create new file and rename it
- build project on another mac

but i get this error everytime

BUT!
If I will create new project and add watchOS target and create new file with this code - project will build successfully.

Why? How i can try to add WCSessionDelegate in my exists project?

I use Xcode9.2, swift4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh...
Thank @Sameer for [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225948/3264552)

WCSessionDelegate has required method

```
public func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?)
```

but my project there is my custom class with name `Error`

that's why the compiler produced an error that does not conform to protocol

Answer (score 1):

Fell into this also and @TyM6JIep 's answer was correct in my case!

Also, it wouldn't accept just `error: Error?`, so I had to use: `Swift.Error?`, even after I renamed my Error enum.

My WatchConnector looks like this - I also added the correct logic for both iOS / WatchOS:

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchConnector: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    func session(
        _ session: WCSession,
        activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
        error: Swift.Error?
    ) {

        
    }

    #if(os(iOS))
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(
        _ session: WCSession
    ) {


    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(
        _ session: WCSession
    ) {


    }
    #endif
}
```